# Modern Warfare 2 "VIP"

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Recently I played Modern Warfare 2, I went to play Free-For-All, then I joined a game, once I was in the game I saw strange things, when I played it said:

```
Welcome to Modern Warfare 2 VIP
```

Something like that, and on the side it had access tools such as

```
Admin tools
Mod tools
Player tools
```

(sorry if it's wrong, but I can't remember everything)

and lastly, a message box saying "awaiting member approval", for some seconds the gameplay was inverted, players had red boxes around them, I could run fast.

Suddenly I was kicked out of the game.

What is this, I was confused about what just happened...

I'm 5th Prestige, Level 70 - legit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you've joined a modified (hacked) server. The player hosting it used a modified executable to make things possible that can't happen on normal servers. The server was probably only intended for members of a certain group, and as you were not a member of that group, you were kicked once the server failed to authenticate you.

Comment: How is this possible? The Activision servers hacked? This happened on PS3 by the way.

Comment: @YouBook It is possible to host a match yourself, even on the PS3. I'm not entirely sure how, because I don't have one, though.